# Better to Return Results or Modify Directly in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is it better to modify internal objects directly in a method or return stuff from a method and make the change outside?

For example, this code makes a change internally, with no unnecessary data exchanged:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.val = 0

    def increment(self):
        self.val = self.val + 1

a = A()
a.increment()
print(a.val)
```

And this code, by comparison, requires the change to be made externally:

```
class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.val = 0

    def increment(self, operand):
        return operand + 1

b = B()
b.val = b.increment(b.val)
print b.val
```

If `increment()` is only ever going to be used to increment *.val, is the first approach stylistically better (more pythonic)?

For the record, I'm using python 2.7.

Comment: Generally you want to return stuff.  Then you can take advantage of all the stuff that functional programming and generator pipelines and the like offer.

Comment: I'm partial towards `a.increment()`. A library of functions might implement #2, but for a function intended to deal only with class variables, #1 is better.

Comment: A is better because it provides encapsulation.

Comment: I think a more meaningful question about which is "better" would be something like `list.sort()` vs `sorted(list)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on what kind of method you are thinking about. In the example you show, it is obviously better to do the assignment of the incremented value inside the method, for a few reasons:

1. It groups all the code related to the goal of the function under the function
2. It makes the function independent, which means that if changes are made to the class (like changing `val` to `value`), code that uses the class will still work
3. An increment function that doesn't increment just isn't logical to create

There are probably more reasons why the first example is better, but maybe in a different example the answer would be different. But usually, modifying an object's variables should be probably done from inside an instancemethod.